# Decrypt & encrypt string within nested loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My goal is to crypt / decrypt some string.
I started with name = 'Programmstrukturen 2' and spalte=5. My crypt def works , but the decrypt not yet.

Here is the code:

```
def crypt(text,spalte):
    output=''
    for x in range(spalte):
        for i in range(spalte-1):
            output+=text[x+spalte*i]
    return output

def decrypt(text,spalte):
    output=''
    for x in range(spalte):
        for i in range(spalte-1):
            output+=text[x+spalte*i]
    return output
```

When i run the simple print function

```
print crypt(name,spalte)
>>Parrrmueomkngst rtu2
print decrypt(eman,spalte)
>>Pmk aunrregtrosurmt2
```

The decrypt function should return the name string.
I know there is something wrong with the loop flow but I cant imagine what is wrong there.

EDIT1:

Is used:

```
name = 'Programmstrukturen 2'
eman = 'Parrrmueomkngst rtu2'
spalte=5
```

Comment: What do you use for laenge? Have you realized that when you crypt it is at same level declaration?

Comment: @RicardoBurillo sorry it was a format mistake, laenge is not used before, or should it be set to 0?

Comment: If you don't use you should remove. Could you add what values are you passing to name and eman to reproduce what you are trying to do? Depending on what you put you may get an error in  output+=text[x+spalte*i] as you don't check the length of it (that I thought laenge was for

Comment: @RicardoBurillo eman is the crypted version of name , added

Comment: Your encryption algorithm is a bit strange: it requires that `len(text)` equals `spalte * (spalte-1)`. If `text` is too short, you'll get an `IndexError: string index out of range`. And if it's too long, some characters will not be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. I suggest you to be careful with the size of spalte as @PM 2Ring has commented. The problem you have is on your decrypt. Its behavour is the same as crypt. You have to append the values to the output on the place that you have crypt them:

```
def decrypt(text, spalte):
    laenge = len(text)
    output = laenge * [""]
    j = 0
    for x in xrange(spalte):
        for i in xrange(spalte - 1):
            output[x + spalte * i] = text[j]
            j += 1
    return "".join(output)
```

Comment: Thanks but gave me more erros then before :     return "".join(output)
TypeError: sequence item 6: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: Kudos for adding variable names in the OP's language.

Comment: I think it is because the output declaration, I have edited the answer. join cannot join None attributes